# Segmentation fault in valgrind, but not in actual run

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

My code when run within Valgrind gives a segmentation fault, but when run normally it doesn't. How is this possible?

The culprit piece of code ,as pointed out by valgrind:

```
static inline void * Vec_PtrEntry( Vec_Ptr_t * p, int i )
{
    assert( i >= 0 && i < p->nSize );
    return p->pArray[i];
}
```

And the message by valgrind:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3290==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
```

Why does this happen, if normally the code runs perfectly? How do I fix this? I need to do some memory profiling of the code.

Comment: It's hard to say what could be wrong without seeing how `p` was created and the definition of `Vec_Ptr_t`.

Comment: valgrind has a built-in gdb server. Did you try attaching gdb and investigating the state of the program at that point?

Comment: Consider yourself lucky; I've seen it happen the other way around.

Comment: On the face of it, you are accessing a null pointer somewhere.  Either `p` is null or `p->pArray` is null, most likely. (You could add a new assertion about this, or extend the existing assertion.)  Software isn't obliged to crash when you invoke undefined behaviour; it can seem to work, and it will usually do so until your boss is showing off your work to the most important client your company has.  At least you've found the problem early.

Comment: In addition to the (very appropriate) "undefined behavior can do anything it wants to, including not crash" reasoning, note that one side effect of running under valgrind is that it drastically changes the performance properties of your program (mainly by making it run slower).  So if you have a bug whose symptoms are only apparent when your program is running slower than normal, valgrind might expose that bug.  This could happen e.g. if you're running a buggy client under valgrind and it's talking to a server that is still running at normal speed.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, undefined behavior does not have to involve a crash. It could function perfectly well. However, that does not appear to be the case here.

We can see from the message

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3290==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
```

That the program has attempted to access address 0x0. This typically means that we have dereferenced a NULL-pointer.

Looking at your code:

```
static inline void * Vec_PtrEntry( Vec_Ptr_t * p, int i )
{
    assert( i >= 0 && i < p->nSize );
    return p->pArray[i];
}
```

We can see that you have attempted to guard against invalid parameters, by asserting that `i>=0` and `i<p->nSize`. There is however, no check that `p` itself is valid.

You could `assert(p)` to ensure it is not NULL. You should do this before the existing assertion.

As to why this only occurs when running under valgrind, an important consideration is that programs run MUCH slower under valgrind, and so you may have exposed an issue that only occurs under heavy load, or at least very different dynamic behavior to the norm.

How can you resolve this and move forward with memory profiling? You need to fix the bug.

1. Use the debugger. gdb integrates nicely with valgrind
2. Use asserts to verify that p is non-null.

Either of these should allow you to see the back-trace, and figure out why p is NULL.

Comment: Agree on the probable cause (was answering in the same way myself; easier to upvote yours). The OP ought to look to operation flow where p is generated and then used. In normal code the two operations will be very close together, and e.g. loops will have no time to execute or do so only once; I suspect there's some code driven by external events (sockets) or running threaded, and p is caught in a race condition. I believe this is actually an *advantage* of Valgrind, as it catches bugs that would otherwise go unnoticed for a long time (or until the Big Show Day, whichever comes first).